# Cleaning Data When Variables are Column Names

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, tidyr

I get data sets like these often where there are variables in the column headers, and the corresponding error measurements are also included.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwSh24a5hm4kSERESlFkeHZXOFE/view?usp=sharing

My question is how to tidy this data set in a quick and simple way to look like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwSh24a5hm4kRDNiSFJoaWFub0E/view?usp=sharing

I'm interested in answers that use dplyr + tidyr and those that do not.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should learn to post `dput(yourdata)` rather than useless (for coding) pictures. This appears to be a fairly basic task using `base::reshape` or `reshape2::melt` and I suspect that pkg:dplyr has a `melt` operation as well. Why not read the help pages and post some code after working through the examples you find there? You will find many worked examples in SO with those function names as search terms as well. (This is also surely a duplicate question.)

Comment: @BondedDust links are `CSV` files, not pictures, but agree that it is a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
df %>%
  # 1. Pivot the table
  gather (g, m, -Timepoint) %>%
  # 2. Get the final Group ID in mGroup
  separate (g, c("Measure", "mGroup"), -2) %>% 
  # 3. Spread the actual Error and Measure in two columns
  spread (Measure, m) %>% 
  # 4. Assign the correct names to final columns
  select (Timepoint, Group = mGroup, Measure = Group, Error = Error_Group) %>%
  # 5. Sort as requested
  arrange (Group, Timepoint)
```

Answer (score 2):

Brute force i would say using only `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Timepoint=c(0L, 7L, 14L, 21L, 28L), Group1=c(50L, 60L, 66L, 88L, 90L),
             Error_Group1=c(3, 4, 6, 8, 2), Group2=c(30L, 60L, 90L, 120L, 150L),
             Error_Group2=c(10L, 14L, 16L, 13L, 25L), Group3=c(44L, 78L, 64L, 88L, 91L),
             Error_Group3=c(2L, 13L, 16L, 4L, 9L))

df <- lapply(1:3, function(x){
  temp <- df %>% select(Timepoint, ends_with(as.character(x))) %>% mutate(Group=x)
  names(temp) <- c("Timepoint", "Measure", "Error", "Group")
  temp <- temp %>% select(Timepoint, Group, Measure, Error)
})

df <- do.call(rbind, df)
df
```

And a bit more elegant with `tidyr` as well

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df <- df %>% gather(temp, Timepoint) 
names(df) <- c("Timepoint", "temp", "values")

df <- df %>% mutate(Group = sub("\\D+", "", temp), temp=sub("\\d", "", temp)) %>% 
  spread(temp, values)

names(df) <- c("Timepoint", "Group", "Error", "Measure")
df
```

Answer (score 1):

From [v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), data.table can `melt` multiple columns simultaneously.. It's both fast and memory efficient.

```
require(data.table) ## v1.9.5+
melt(setDT(df), id=1L, measure=patterns("^Group", "^Error"), 
        variable.name="Group", value.name = c("Measure", "Error"))
#    Timepoint Group Measure Error
# 1:         0     1      50     3
# 2:         7     1      60     4
# 3:        14     1      66     6
# 4:        21     1      88     8
# 5:        28     1      90     2
# ...
```

Comment: I tried to install the developer version of data.table.  Had some issues and gave up.  Looking forward to seeing the `melt` function in the next cran release.  Thanks for your time!!!!